# How can i crop live camera photos and save in gallery in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-camera

i have create camera application. i want to crop photo when capture photo.
[image]

i am trying to capture only middle part **or** only save middle part on gallery using photo cropping.

i am also add some more functionality to capture 4 photo continuously and add frame on photos like that :

[image]

finally save above picture on gallery.

i have only one problem that is i can not crop the middle part of photo please suggest me how can i crop the image easily **or** only capture middle part of camera.

And can we capture only middle part displayed in upper screenshot?
Or we have to first capture and than crop the image?

please suggest me

thank you